# How can I know if spark application/job is idle/waiting for resources?

Tags: apache-spark, resources, apache-spark-standalone

I'm very new to spark, so forgive me if some of my concepts are not right.

My main "problem" is that I want to know if my spark application is waiting or idle for resources. Does the state of the job/application will always indicate that? I don't think so.

In the development that I'm working right now, there are going to be a LOT of spark applications. Those applications can run at the same time, or with a small interval of time.

My Spark Driver is configured to have 1 master and 2 workers (each in a different machine). I'm also running my application with Spark Standalone Cluster. In spark master UI (port 8080) I have some additional informations:

[image]

Here is my spark master conf file:

```
spark.master spark://myServer:7077
spark.sql.caseSensitive false
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 90000
spark.network.timeout 400000
spark.executor.heartbeat.maxFailures 10
spark.shuffle.registration.timeout 500000
spark.shuffle.push.finalize.timeout 600s
spark.files.fetchTimeout 600s
spark.rpc.lookupTimeout 600s
spark.scheduler.excludeOnFailure.unschedulableTaskSetTimeout 600s
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir file:/opt/spark/logs/spark-events/
spark.history.fs.logDirectory file:/opt/spark/logs/spark-events/
spark.executor.logsDirectory /opt/spark/logs
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled true
spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled true
spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled true
spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled true
spark.executor.memory 5g
spark.executor.cores 2
spark.driver.memory 8g
spark.driver.cores 4
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout 600s
spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.port 7078
spark.blockManager.port 7087
spark.driver.blockManager.port 7011
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.shuffle.service.port 7337
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.worker.cleanup.enabled true
```

Ok, so now you know that i have:

- 3 workers (including the master)
- 30 cores
- 90GB of memory
- Using standalone cluster
- Dynamic allocation is enabled
- 15 executors (I don't now how this number of executors was set, but I have this information).
- Each executor has 5GB of memory
- Each partition of my data has 4GB
- Spark version is 3.5

And as I already explained, in a real scenario, I can run 2, 3 or more applications at the same time. If one of these applications uses a very large table, with many partitions and very large data, that application will use a lot of resources. If I run several large applications at the same time, some application will be idle for resources.

I integrate spark logs into Livy, so in Livy, I was able to get the following log:

```
2024-03-25 09:11:31 INFO  - Requesting 1 new executor because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 1 for resource profile id: 0)
...
2024-03-25 09:11:46 WARN  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2024-03-25 09:12:01 WARN  - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2024-03-25 09:12:06 INFO  - Executor added: app-x-y/0 on worker-x-IP-z (IP:z) with 2 core(s)
2024-03-25 09:12:06 INFO  - Granted executor ID app-x-y/0 on hostPort IP:zwith 2 core(s), 4.0 GiB RAM
2024-03-25 09:12:06 INFO  - Executor updated: app-x-y/0 is now RUNNING
2024-03-25 09:12:09 INFO  - Executor added: app-x-y/1 on worker-X-IP-z(IP:z) with 2 core(s)
2024-03-25 09:12:09 INFO  - Granted executor ID app-x-y/1 on hostPort IP:z with 2 core(s), 4.0 GiB RAM
2024-03-25 09:12:09 INFO  - Executor updated: app-x-y/1 is now RUNNING
2024-03-25 09:12:11 INFO  - Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (IP:u) with ID 0,  ResourceProfileId 0
2024-03-25 09:12:11 INFO  - New executor 0 has registered (new total is 1)
2024-03-25 09:12:11 INFO  - Registering block manager IP:k with 2.2 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, IP, k, None)
2024-03-25 09:12:12 INFO  - Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (IP, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7865 bytes) 
2024-03-25 09:12:12 INFO  - Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (IP, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7865 bytes) 
2024-03-25 09:12:12 INFO  - Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on IP:k(size: 12.0 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
2024-03-25 09:12:14 INFO  - Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (IP:u) with ID 1,  ResourceProfileId 0
2024-03-25 09:12:14 INFO  - New executor 1 has registered (new total is 2)
```

From what I understand, the log message "*Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources*" indicates that this application is not following the normal flow, as it is waiting for resources.

My problem is not the amount of resources, as the machine has a resource specification that I cannot change. However, I would like to know easily when an application waits for resources. Any functionality in spark Web UI? Any specific tag in spark-defaults.conf file? Any function in the Spark API?